# error in Tslint upgrading

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, tslint

Hi I am unable to get through this error please help me with this error and I have tried sudo apt-get install nodejs legacy and etc but was not able to find the solution

```
       TS    build-rt
    /home/gautam/sd.js-master/node_modules/tslint/lib/ruleLoader.js:29
            throw new Error(ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ^

Error: 
            Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration:
            no-trailing-comma
            Try upgrading TSLint and/or ensuring that you have all necessary custom rules installed.
            If TSLint was recently upgraded, you may have old rules configured which need to be cleaned up.

    at Object.loadRules (/home/gautam/sd.js-master/node_modules/tslint/lib/ruleLoader.js:29:15)
    at Linter.lint (/home/gautam/sd.js-master/node_modules/tslint/lib/tslint.js:59:44)
    at processFile (/home/gautam/sd.js-master/node_modules/tslint/lib/tslint-cli.js:138:29)
    at /home/gautam/sd.js-master/node_modules/tslint/lib/tslint-cli.js:177:74
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gautam/sd.js-master/node_modules/tslint/lib/tslint-cli.js:177:41)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
make: *** [build-rt] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The no-trailing-comma rule was removed, it has been replaced by the trailing-comma rule (#687)

EDIT:
In your /tslint.json file remove the use of "no-trailing-comma". It can be replaced with the new "trailing-comma" rule which you can find more about here: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/trailing-comma/

The new rule adds options for multiline and singleline, which can be "always" or "never":

```
"trailing-comma": [true,
    {
        "multiline": "always",
        "singleline": "never"
    }
],
```

If you just want to turn it off you can add this:

```
"trailing-comma": [false],
```

Comment: Ok I have seen that in github but what is the solution

Comment: Change "no-trailing-comma" in your tslint.json file to "trailing-comma"